# A word to describe "believing all your emotions are truth"

Tags: single-word-requests

I remember finding a word like this, but I can't find it any more.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. You need to include context and example sentence where this word would be used. The following is the rule of this community. **Questions on choosing an ideal word or phrase must include information on how it will be used in order to be answered**. For help writing a good word or phrase request, see: [About single word requests](http://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info). Please edit your question accordingly.Please take the [tour](http://english.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit our [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 4):

It could be ***irrationalism***, which isn't defined exactly like your title, but is defined as:

> **[ir·ra·tion·al·ism](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=irrationalism)** (*n.*) Belief in feeling, instinct, or other nonrational forces rather than reason.

That might fit the bill, but, without any further information, it's hard to tell if that's the elusive word you're looking for.

Answer (score 2):

One can assume that emotions and imagination overlap to a large extent.

The word *delusional* could be used:

> **delusion** 1
>
> a conception or image created by the imagination and having no
>   objective reality

{[M-W Thesaurus](http://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/delusion)}

[Dr. Anthony Komaroff  {Harvard Medical School}](http://www.askdoctork.com/the-word-is-used-frequently-but-what-does-being-delusional-really-mean-201306084949) further states:

> A delusion is a false belief that is based on an incorrect
>   interpretation of reality. A person with delusional disorder will
>   firmly hold on to a false belief despite clear evidence to the
>   contrary.
>
> Delusions can be caused by mental illnesses....
>
> Delusions often are beliefs that could not possibly be true. If I
>   believed that I were Joan of Arc, or that the moon was going to smash
>   into the Earth tomorrow, those would be delusions.

Answer (score 0):

You could say the person is a **[dogmatist](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/dogmatist)**:

> a ​person who ​believes too ​strongly that ​their ​personal ​opinions or ​beliefs are ​correct

You could say they exhibit **[self-partiality](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/self-partiality)**:

> a prejudice in favor of one's own claims or interests

They may also believe their views and emotions are **[peremptory](http://tfd.com/peremptory)**

> Subject to no further debate or dispute; final and unassailable